# How to get device MAC address in Flutter DART?

Tags: flutter, dart, mac-address

I need to access the MAC address of the device.

I tried many packages like get_mac, mac_address, macadress_gen from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) but always got `02:00:00:00:00:00` as my MAC address, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: As-salamu alaykum. Have you tried running on an actual device instead of emulator?

Comment: wa alaykoum salam, of course my friend i'm runing with my device with usb debbuging

Comment: There is no way for an app to get the MAC address on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

All Android devices return that as the MAC address, to prevent it from being used as a hardware ID.  To get the real id you need the LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions

Comment: Thanks for your answer! i've added those two lines as u said:
<uses-permission android:name="LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
but still don't get the mac address :( also there is no LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS permission on the API https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

Comment: @AbdallahRaies There is, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo#getMacAddress()

Comment: still not working after adding permissions, i'm using now flutter get_mac package and the method getMac returns null always